# C# TransparentProxies and Array Resizing

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-2.0

C# TransparentProxies and Array Resizing

I have a C# object which is of type System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy which is a proxy for a remote Profile class.

My Profile class has an array of alarms.

I am adding two more alarms to the Profile class. This works on the local side, but because alarms were implemented as an array, the remote side's Length is two short.

How do I resize my remote array such that I can store two more items?

I've tried:

1. `Array.Resize( remoteProfile.profiles[i].alarms, NEW_SIZE );`
2. `remoteProfile.profiles[i] = new Profile(remoteProfile.profiles[i]);`

   The copy constructor creates a new profile with the proper size.
3. `remoteProfile.profiles[i].ResizeAlarms();`

   ResizeAlarms creates a new array, copies the old values over, then assigns it to the alarms member.
4. `var newProfile = new Profile( remoteProfile.profiles[i] );
   remoteProfile.profiles[i].alarms = newProfile.alarms;`

Any suggestions? (This is in C# 2.0.)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved this issue. Take heed future Google visitor.

The problem came from the object identifying itself as, "system.runtime.remoting.proxies.__transparentproxy". For whatever reason, I was unable to modify these like a normal object.

Fortunately, in my situation, the object was only copied once and then it was ignored.

Therefore, to get around this, I created a copy-constructor for the object's class which copied everything over. I then used `theProfile = new Profile(remoteProfile);`. This allowed me to access and modify the contents as needed.